# .net core with typescript typings install issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typescript, asp.net-core, typescript-typings

I've just downloaded VS2015 community edition and I'm playing with migrating one of my old MVC projects to .NET Core MVC. It's kind of going ok but I wrote all the client side code in TypeScript for my old project which is now proving to be a pain in the butt to setup (imho). I've managed to get my TypeScript files working now after configuring all these new JSON config files that are driving everything, however I've now just added back a number of 'definitleytyped' packages (which seem to be nowhere obvious in the project) but my TypeScript is erroring as it can't recognise '$' for jQuery??

I've searched google and found that I now should be using 'typings' instead but for the life of me I'm just not getting anywhere. Everyone says run 'NPM install typings --global' but whether I used PowerShell or cmd or the VS dev command line 'npm' is unrecognised??

Help please!

Comment: Visual Studio comes with a version of `Nodejs`(requirement to run `npm`), then you can configure your package.json and hit restore packages (right-click on npm dependencies). I prefer to install my version of `Nodejs`. In this [tutorial](https://github.com/fabriciokoch/AspnetcoreAngular/tree/master/Part1) you can find how to configure a external version of `Nojejs`. If you configure Nodejs outside VisualStudio, you can run `npm` commands in a cmd prompt.

Comment: Hi Fabricio - thanx for that, I've now managed to get the 'typings' package installed now but installing/reinstalling the nuget definitlytyped packages for jquery seems to do nothing, no files are added anywhere to my project but nuget says that they're installed, do I need to now install these 'typings' in a different way (i.e. not use nuget versions)? Are there other versions?

Comment: If you add a package with nuget, the files are stored in `C:\Users\USER_NAME\.nuget\packages` folder or in the current folder. If you add a package with npm,  the files are stored in the current folder (inside node_modules folder) or in `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules` folder.

Comment: I installed node.js outside visual studio and ran the 'npm install typings --global' but this did nothing to my project that I can see. However, I managed to get the 'typings' package added in my project by editing the package.json and put "typings" : "1.4.0". But this is as far as I've got, can't figure out how to get jquery typings into my project... Why are we not just using nuget like in VS2013, I seem to now have loads of *.json config files everywhere its such a mess!!!! help!

Comment: With your `npm install typings --global` command, you've installed typings CLI. Now it's in your path. You just need to add the configuration files (tsconfig.json, for example) in your project in visual studio. Your visual studio must use the Nodejs version that is in your path. The tutorial in my first comment shows how to do that.

Comment: Thanks, I've got it sorted now - didn't show up until I unloaded and reloaded the project

Comment: Nice! I posted my comments as an answer. Please, accept is as an answer to help other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `Nodejs` in your computer and configure Visual Studio to use the version you've just installed. Check this [tutorial](https://github.com/fabriciokoch/AspnetcoreAngular/tree/master/Part1) to see how it's done.

Open a command window and install the `typings CLI` with the following command:
`npm install typings --global`

Now, add the configuration files (e.g. tsconfig.json) and all should works.

Answer (score 1):

1 - install **npm** https://nodejs.org

2 - install **typings**

```
npm install typings -g
```

3 - Change the settings in VS to use your PATH first, this is the main issue always when you install npm, VS now comes with npm embedded.

```
Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> External Web Tools
```

Select **$(PATH)** and with the arrows (right corner) move the PATH to the first row.

4 - Now `cd` to your project path and `typings install jquery --save`

5 - This will install the typing definition needed to use jquery inside of a .ts file, type `JQueryStatic` and use it instead of `$`.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks I've used this to configure it within VS works great